# Linux >2.6.33: could sendfile() be used to implement a faster 'cat'?

Tags: linux, cat, sendfile

Having to concatenate lots of large files into an even larger single one, we currently use

```
cat file1 file2 ... output_file
```

but are wondering whether it could be done faster than with that old friend.

Reading the man page of `sendfile()`, one can specify an offset into *input_file*, from where to send the remainder of it to *output_file*. But: can I also specify an offset into *output_file*? 
Or could I simply loop over all input files, simply by leaving open my output FD and sendfile()'ing repeatedly into it, effectively concatenating the *input_files*?
In other words: would the filepointer into my output FD remain at its end, if I do not close it nor seek() in it?

Does anybody knows of such a `cat` implementation using `sendfile()`?

---

Admittedly, I'm an admin, not a programmer, so please bear with my lack of 'real' coding knowledge...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the file pointer of the output fd will remain at its end (if the file is new or is not bigger than the data you already wrote to it).

The documentation for [sendfile()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendfile) explicitly mentions (emphasis mine):

> In Linux kernels before 2.6.33, `out_fd` must refer to a socket. Since
>   Linux 2.6.33 it can be any file. **If it is a regular file, then
>   `sendfile()` changes the file offset appropriately**.

I personally never saw an implementation of `cat` that relies on `sendfile()`, maybe because 2.6.33 is quite recent, and `out_fd` could not be `fileno(stdout)` before. `sendfile()` is also not portable, so doing that would result in a version of `cat` that only runs on Linux 2.6.33+ (although I guess it can still be implemented as a platform-dependent optimization activated at compile time).

Comment: ... you seem to have another "man sendfile" than me! But thanks for the explanations - that helps.
Yes, that sendfile-based cat would not be portable nor for older kernel revisions, but if it's faster than what we have now, I'd of course be happy to accept these restrictions!