# C streams: Copy data from one stream to another directly, without using a buffer

Tags: c, linux, stream, posix

I want to copy data from one stream to another. Now normally, I would do it this way:

```
n = fread(buffer, 1, bufsize, fin);
fwrite(buffer, 1, n, fout);
```

Is there a way to write the data directly from `fin` to `fout`, without going through a buffer, i.e. instead of `fin->buffer->fout`, I want to directly do `fin->fout` (no buffer).

Is it possible to do so in ANSI C? If not, is it possible to do it with POSIX functions? Or a Linux-specific solution?

Comment: I don't think so, because AFAIK freopen() can only mangle either input or output streams, but seems not to be able to connect an input to an output.

Comment: It's Linux and /output will actually be a named pipe - but I don't know how that solves the problem.

Comment: Some process writes data to the stdin of my program. The job of my program is to set up a named pipe and put that data into the named pipe.

Comment: "Some process" does not know the name of the named pipe, the job of my program is to find a free name, set up the pipe, etc.

Comment: In fact my program does a little bit more than that - it also decides whether a pipe is used or another interface used. It's certainly not redundant ;-)

Comment: I prefer the old-school file-descriptors instead of FILE*, but I guess that's OK, so I'm fine with your edit. BTW, I looked up the source-code of "cat" and it also does it with a buffer - so I wonder whether it's even possible.

Comment: No, your question is good, really, I've wondered it, too. I think it's just not worth it, for I/O with harddisk certainly, but even with pipes, the overhead is probably negligible. I think if you really want to avoid copying, shared memory is the way to go. I deleted all my comments btw, so they don't clutter.

Comment: As for `cat` being implemented that way, you might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15769970/linux-2-6-33-could-sendfile-be-used-to-implement-a-faster-cat

Answer (score 9, accepted):

2 possible Linux-only solutions are [splice()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/splice.2.html) and [sendfile()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html). What they do is copy data without it ever leaving kernel space, thus making a potentially significant performance optimization.

Note that **both have limitations**:

- [sendfile()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html) requires a socket for its output for Linux kernels before 2.6.33, after that, any file can be the output, and also it requires the input to support `mmap()` operations, meaning the input can't be `stdin` or a pipe.
- [splice()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/splice.2.html) requires one of the input or output streams to be a pipe (not sure about both), and also for kernel versions 2.6.30.10 and older, it requires the file system for the stream that is not a pipe to support splicing.

**Edit:** Note that [some filesystems might not support splicing for Linux 2.6.30.10 and below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3668131/492336).

Comment: sendfile() sounded promising, but I always get EINVAL, probably because according to the manpage: "an mmap(2)-like operation is not available for in_fd" - which sounds plausible for stdin.

Comment: splice() works on my desktop (Linux 3.11), but doesn't work on my actual target system, probably because of vhost-limitations (also gettting EINVAL, probably because according to the manpage: "Target filesystem doesn't support splicing".

Comment: I'll accept your answer, but you should remove sendfile() from it.

Comment: You can look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638657/which-file-systems-support-splicing-via-linuxs-splice2

Comment: OK, that clears it up, my cheap vhosted Linux 2.6 is not good enough for splice()... Thanks a lot for your support though.

Comment: I rewrote my answer to highlight the limitations for both functions. I've left `sendfile()`, because it might work in some cases where `splice()` does not, since it doesn't require a pipe.